# Cerberus coercion within nested list

Tags: python, list, validation, cerberus, coerce

I get unexpected behaviour for the following code:

```
import cerberus
v = cerberus.Validator()
schema = {'list_of_values': {'type': 'list',
                             'schema': {'items': [{'type': 'string', 'coerce': str},
                                                  {'type': 'integer', 'coerce': int}]}}
                             }
document = {'list_of_values': [['hello', 100], [123, "122"]]}
v.validate(document, schema)
v.errors
```

I am expecting to have no errors, as the coercion should take care of the types. But I am getting

```
{'list_of_values': [{1: [{0: ['must be of string type'],
     1: ['must be of integer type']}]}]}
```

Is this a bug? Am I misunderstanding how the coercion works?

Comment: this might actually be a bug.

Comment: actually, i can't reoroduce the demonstrated behaviour.

Comment: @funky-future: I just ran the same code again, and I'm getting the same validation errors.
Python 3.7 and cerberus 1.2
Ubuntu 16.04
What might be the reason that I encounter it and you don't?

Comment: if you can reproduce it with a test, please submit it with a pull request.

Comment: @funky-future I can reproduce the issue, I lack the project knowledge to submit a failing test for this.

Answer (score 1):

@funky-future

Something not right on your end, I can indeed reproduce the problem just by copy paste the example into the prompt:

```
>>> import cerberus
>>> v = cerberus.Validator()
>>> schema = {'list_of_values': {'type': 'list',
...                              'schema': {'items': [{'type': 'string', 'coerce': str},
...                                                   {'type': 'integer', 'coerce': int}]}}
...                              }
>>> document = {'list_of_values': [['hello', 100], [123, "122"]]}
>>> v.validate(document, schema)
False
>>> v.errors
{'list_of_values': [{1: [{0: ['must be of string type'], 1: ['must be of integer type']}]}]}
```

Python3.5.2, cerberus1.2